# While sending AT commands to ESP8266 (esp-01) I get ERROR

Tags: esp8266

Some of it is OK

```
ATE0
OK

AT+GMR
AT version:0.21.0.0
SDK version:0.9.5
OK
```

But most of the commands return ERROR. For example

```
AT+CWMODE_CUR=?
ERROR
```

What can be a problem?

Comment: `AT+CWMODE_CUR=1` or `AT+CWMODE_CUR?`

Comment: any of it gives ERROR - 
AT+CWMODE_CUR? 
ERROR
AT+CWMODE_CUR=1 
ERROR

Comment: it is a very old AT firmware version. try AT+CWMODE=1

Comment: I see. Thank you.

Comment: Hmm...Seems like the last official version is 0.20. I have 0.21.

Comment: I found a newer version - 0.23. Now it works. Thank you.

Comment: https://www.espressif.com/en/support/download/at?keys=&field_type_tid%5B%5D=799